# How to open simulator created by xcode server?

Tags: ios-simulator, osx-server, xcode-server

I'm working on running UItest on Xcode server (created by Osx server). 
Before testing I need to do some manual actions on simulator (tap to allow notification, location, background location, validation, wait for download data ...). 
Xcode server created another instance of simulator because I manually opened the same simulator (ipad air 2) and nothings on that. I'm unable to find the simulator created by xcode server.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode Server runs under a separate role account user.  Anything you need to do to set up your tests needs to be done in an automated fashion as part of your test infrastructure.

You should be able to use Xcode UI Testing to click the (expected) alerts.